# MVC3 Razor concatenation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, concatenation, razor

I am trying to create an id for an input by doing the following

```
    id="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.Name + "_" +  @ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("FromDate")"
```

but it is coming through with id="propertyName +".  How can I concatenate the two together with an underscore in the middle in a razor view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `@(expression)` syntax to express an explicit code expression.

You need to be explicit here because the space after `@ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.Name` is not a valid character for a C# identifier so the evalutation stops there.

The algorithm used by Razor for processing implicit code expression is the following:

1. Parse an identifier - As soon as we see a character that isn't valid in a C# or VB identifier, we stop and move to step 2
2. Check for brackets - If we see "(" or "[", go to step 2.1., otherwise, go to step 3

   1. Parse until the matching ")" or "]" (we track nested "()" and "[]" pairs and ignore "()[]" we see in strings or comments)
   2. Go back to step 2
3. Check for a "." - If we see one, go to step 3.1, otherwise, DO NOT ACCEPT THE "." as code, and go to step 4

   1. If the character AFTER the "." is a valid identifier, accept the "." and go back to step 1, otherwise, go to step 4
4. Done!

(Taken from [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx))

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
id="@(ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.Name)_@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("FromDate"))"
```

or like this:

```
id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}", ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.Name, ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("FromDate"))"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
id="@(ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.Name + "_" +  ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("FromDate"))"
```